# Why does the FileReader stream read 239, 187, 191 from a textfile?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a text file with a just a character 'T' inside, and I have created a read stream to output to the console what is being read and I got 239, 187, 191 and 84, I understand that 84 represents 'T', I know 239, 187, 191 represent other characters as well but I don't have those characters in my text file, what is going on??

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
      FileInputStream in = null;

      try {
         in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");         
         int c;
         while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
             System.out.println(c);

         }
      }finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's the utf8 byte order mark. Some editors save the BOM inside the file (in order to be used as a header) which regularly causes confusion because it is optional.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure it's not `239 187 191`? (`EF BB BF` in hex)

You're seeing the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of the file:

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK (BOM), whose appearance as a magic number at the start of a text stream can signal several things to a program reading the text:
>
> The byte order, or endianness, of the text stream;
> The fact that the text stream's encoding is Unicode, to a high level of confidence;
> Which Unicode encoding the text stream is encoded as.